# Ignore the first and last row in a query result

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a query where I want to ignore the first and the last row of the result query.

My result query is retrieving the sum of all mediums in the last hour grouped by 5 minutes.

To ignore the first record I'm using offset(1) and to ignore the last i was trying to do a limit in my id field, ordering by timestamp desc.

My query:

```
ws_controller_hist=>  
SELECT to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' FROM TIMESTAMP) / 300)) * 300) 
AS timestamp_min,
       TYPE,
       floor(sum(medium[1]))
FROM default_dataset
WHERE TYPE LIKE 'ap_clients.wlan0'
  AND TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '85 minutes'
  AND organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638'
  AND id NOT IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM default_dataset
     ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
     LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY timestamp_min,
         TYPE
ORDER BY timestamp_min ASC
OFFSET 1;

     timestamp_min      |       type       | floor
------------------------+------------------+-------
 2017-12-19 14:20:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    38
 2017-12-19 14:25:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    37
 2017-12-19 14:30:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    39
 2017-12-19 14:35:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    42
 2017-12-19 14:40:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    43
 2017-12-19 14:45:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    44
 2017-12-19 14:50:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    45
 2017-12-19 14:55:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    45
 2017-12-19 15:00:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    43
 2017-12-19 15:05:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    43
 2017-12-19 15:10:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    50
 2017-12-19 15:15:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    52
 2017-12-19 15:20:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    50
 2017-12-19 15:25:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    53
 2017-12-19 15:30:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    49
 2017-12-19 15:35:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    39
 2017-12-19 15:40:00+00 | ap_clients.wlan0 |    16
```

This is not ignoring the last record because i have the same records dont using the subquery " `and id not in (select id from default_dataset order by timestamp desc limit 1)` "

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query in an outer query and use `lag` and `OFFSET` to do the trick.

```
SELECT lag(timestamp_min)    OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_min) AS timestamp_min,
       lag(type)             OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_min) AS type,
       lag(sum_first_medium) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_min),
FROM (SELECT to_timestamp(
                floor(
                   (extract('epoch' FROM TIMESTAMP) / 300)
                ) * 300
             ) AS timestamp_min,
             type,
             floor(sum(medium[1])) AS sum_first_medium
      FROM default_dataset
      WHERE type = 'ap_clients.wlan0'
        AND timestamp > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '85 minutes'
        AND organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638'
      GROUP BY timestamp_min, type) lagme
OFFSET 2;
```

Comment: I got this "ERROR:  record type has not been registered"

Comment: Right, silly me. The edited answer should work better.

Comment: ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT lag(timestamp_min) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS timestamp_min

Comment: It worked, but what if I have ap_clients.wlan0 and ap_clients.wlan1 and i want to sum both i just need to do in the like condition this "WHERE type LIKE 'ap_clients.wlan%'" ?

Comment: As long as you understand the pattern I used (nested queries, `lag` and `OFFSET`), you should be able to adapt the query to your needs.

Comment: The query is not returning any data, if I make a "select * from default_dataset where type ='ap_clients.wlan0'" I have rows, but the query dont return anything...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably bit long, but will do exactly as you requested

```
SELECT z.*
    FROM
(SELECT y.*, min(row_number) OVER(), max(row_number) OVER()
    FROM 
(SELECT x.*, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp_min)
   FROM 
(SELECT to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' FROM TIMESTAMP) / 300)) * 300) 
AS timestamp_min,
       TYPE,
       floor(sum(medium[1]))
FROM default_dataset
WHERE TYPE LIKE 'ap_clients.wlan0'
  AND TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '85 minutes'
  AND organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638'
  AND id NOT IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM default_dataset
     ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
     LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY timestamp_min,
         TYPE
ORDER BY timestamp_min ASC
) AS x
 ) AS y
 ) AS z WHERE row_number NOT IN (min, max)
```